# How to generate a SAS Token with Curl?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Using Azure CLI, it is possible to generate a SAS Token easily:

```
SAS_TOKEN=$( \
  az iot hub generate-sas-token \
  --hub-name $IOT_HUB \
  --device-id $DEVICE \
  --query sas \
  --output tsv)
```

I would like to generate the SAS token using **curl**, calling an Azure public API.
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API, the workaround is that you can use Azure Functions to generate an IoT SAS Token, then call Azure function using curl to get the SAS token.

Reference:

[Using Azure Functions to generate an IoT SAS Token](https://kevinsaye.wordpress.com/2017/01/05/using-azure-functions-to-generate-an-iot-sas-token/)